# Smart_listing Gem sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, smart-listing

Im integrating [Smart_listing](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing) gem onto my Rails App. I have a ***Beer table*** in my database and a ***beer_type*** column. Right now im trying to set up a sorting function where Users can filter different types of beer. Similar to this functionality [example](http://sf.hopsy.beer/menu).

Right now it will filter each one type of beer perfectly. However whenever there is more than 1 beer type checked, it would not display the beer types together.

> product.rb

```
scope :with_beer_type_ales, -> (product) { where('beer_type ILIKE?', "%ales%") }
scope :with_beer_type_cream, -> (product) { where('beer_type ILIKE?', "%cream%") }
scope :like, ->(args) { where("name ILIKE? OR beer_type ILIKE? OR description ILIKE?", "%#{args}%", "%#{args}%", "%#{args}%")}
```

> products_controller.rb

```
def index
 products_scope = Product.all
 # Make users initally sorted by name ascending
 products_scope = products_scope.like(params[:filter]) if params[:filter]


 products_scope=products_scope.with_beer_type_ales(params[:with_beer_type_ales]) if params[:with_beer_type_ales] == "1"
products_scope = products_scope.with_beer_type_cream(params[:with_beer_type_cream]) if  params[:with_beer_type_cream] == "1"

 @products = smart_listing_create :products, 
                       products_scope, 
                       partial: "products/list",
                       page_sizes: [10, 20, 30], 
                       default_sort: {name: "asc"}
end
```

> index.html.erb

```
<%= smart_listing_controls_for(:products, {class: "form-inline text-left"}) do %>
     <div class="form-group filter input-append" id="search">
        <%= text_field_tag :filter, '', class: "search form-control",  
          placeholder: "Search...", autocomplete: :off %>
          <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" type="<%= :submit %>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
      </div>

        <h4>Sort By Type:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li class="checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox inline">
              <%= hidden_field_tag :with_beer_type_ales, "0" %>
              <%= check_box_tag :with_beer_type_ales %> Ales
            </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="checkbox inline">
                <%= hidden_field_tag :with_beer_type_cream, "0" %>
              <%= check_box_tag :with_beer_type_cream %> Cream
            </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a row in your database that is a beer of both types?

Comment: @shelvacu no I don't. But I want to be able to tick both "Ales" and "Cream" beer types and it will display all beers that have beer_type "Ales" and all beers that are "Cream". Not filtering beer with "Ales and Cream"

Answer (score 0):

You want OR not AND. When you specify multiple `where` clauses in  a chain, rails defaults to AND.

```
q = Beer.where(true)
q = q.or.where('beer_type ILIKE?', "%ales%")  if params[:with_beer_type_ales] == "1"
q = q.or.where('beer_type ILIKE?', "%cream%") if params[:with_beer_type_cream] == "1"
```

Comment: hmm I get what you what you mean. Thanks! However I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but its not working. Can you point me further to the right direction ?